# Why Android JUnit testing system do not run my ActivityTestCase

Tags: android, junit

I want to write junit test using ActivityTestCase
Test looks something like that

```
public class GenralTest extends ActivityTestCase<MyActivity> {


    public GeneralTest(Class<MyActivity> activityClass) {
    super(MyActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    public void testBasicDB(){
// test
    }
}
```

When I run Unit testing from intellij or maven this test doesn't even starts

Answer (score 1):

Solution is quite simple, It has to be constructor with no arguments

```
public GenralTest() {
    super(MyActivity.class);
}
```

IDE suggested me constructor with this class argument

this is small thing but I hope it'll help somebody